# proftpd cannot start neither in standalone nor in inetd/xinetd mode

Tags: 16.04, proftpd

I am running ProFTPD on Ubuntu 16.04 and whenever I try to start it up, I just get the message

```
ProFTPD Warning: cannot start neither in standalone nor in inetd/xinetd mode. Check your configuration.
```

I can attatch the config file if you need it.